# If $X \hookrightarrow Y$ is compact and $A \subset X$ is closed, then $A \hookrightarrow Y$ is also compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X=(X, \|\cdot\|_X)$ and $Y=(Y, \|\cdot\|_Y)$ be Banach spaces such that $X \hookrightarrow Y$, that is, $X$ is continuous embedding in $Y$. In other words, the inclusion map $i: X \longrightarrow Y$ is continous. Suppose further that $i$ is compact operator, that is, $X$ is compactly embedded in $Y$.

Let $A \subset X$ be a closed subspace of $X$. Thus, $A=(A, ||\cdot||_X)$ is a Banach space.

**Question.** It's true that $A$ is compactly embedded in $Y$?

I think it's true, since $A \subset X \subset Y$, $i: A \longrightarrow Y$ is continuous and a compact operator. My reasoning is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the inclusion map $\iota:A\hookrightarrow X$ is bounded and thus continuous, by the ideal property of the compact operators $I^{\infty}(X,Y)=\{T\in\mathcal{L}(X,Y): T \text{ compact}\}$, which says that for a bounded linear operator $S\in\mathcal{L}(Z,X)$ we have  $TS\in I^{\infty}(Z,Y)$ you see that
$$A\overset{\iota}{\hookrightarrow}X\overset{i}{\hookrightarrow}Y$$
yields a compact embedding $i\circ \iota.$

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!

Comment: From this,can I to conclude that $A$ is continuous embedding in $X$?

Comment: Indeed more: You can even conclude that $i\circ\iota:A\hookrightarrow Y$ is a comopact embedding, because $A$ is embedded continuously in $X$ and $X$ compactly in $Y$

Comment: If $i$ is only continuous (not compact) then by similar arguments can I to conclude that $A$ is continuous embedding in $Y$?

Comment: @Guilherme de Loreno Yes, of course, there are good reasons though why one is especially interested in compact embeddings

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In fact, because both $X$ and $Y$ are Banach, these are also [Hausdorff spaces](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa%C3%A7o_de_Hausdorff). A closed subset of a compact Hausdorff space is also compact, so $A$ is compact itself and the result follows from the fact that $i$ is continuous.

Comment: But you has prove that $A$ is compact. This implies that $A  \hookrightarrow Y$ is compact?

Comment: Yes. Because $X\hookrightarrow Y$ is continuous, the restriction to $A$ must also be continuous. Once $A$ is compact, its image is compact.